# Tcl variable inside procedure scope issue

Tags: variables, scope, tcl, procedure

I need help with variable scope in tcl

%cat b.tcl

```
set x 1
set y 2
set z 3
```

%cat a.tcl

```
proc test {} {
  source b.tcl
}
test
puts "x : $x, y: $y, z: $z\n"
```

When I execute this I get can't read "x": no such variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `source` command is almost exactly just the same as this procedure:

```
proc source {filename} {
    # Read in the contents of the file
    set f [open $filename]
    set script [read $f]
    close $f

    # Evaluate the script in the caller's scope
    uplevel 1 $script
}
```

(There are nuances with argument parsing, how the channel is configured, and how things are set up for things like `info script` and `info frame`, which make the real thing more complicated. They don't change the overall impression from the above. The real code is implemented in C.)

In particular, the script is run in the stack frame of the caller, and not in the stack frame of `source` itself or the global scope. If you want to source in some other scope, you need to use `uplevel` with the call to `source`:

```
proc test {} {
    # Run the script globally
    uplevel "#0" [list source b.tcl]
}
```

In the case where the *filename* is free of Tcl metacharacters (commonly true of your own code), you can be sloppy:

```
proc test {} {
    # Run the script in the caller's scope
    uplevel 1 source b.tcl
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay look like `return [uplevel 1 source $file]` works! Thank you

Comment: This reads more like a comment, better tick Donal's answer and turn it into a proper comment.